# Bounds on a triple integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

For a problem I am to determine the volume between the surfaces $z=x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, and above the disk $x^2+y^2\le1$. Normally I am able to visualize what the limits of integration will be, but for whatever reason I can't see to see this one; the "above the disk" constraint is throwing me off.

My attempt: $$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{x^2+y^2}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} dzdydx$$

I can do the actual integration no problem, but it is just the bounds that I am kind of confused on. I'm guessing this type of problem can be done (perhaps more easily) using spherical coordinates, however, my class has not gotten there yet and I would appreciate it if I could be given suggestions in Cartesian coordinates.

Thanks!

Comment: Your setup looks fine. (This is probably easiest to calculate in cylindrical coordinates.)

Comment: If we rotate the curve $x=f(z), \quad 0 \le z \le 2$, about the $z$-axis it describes a so-called surface of revolution. The volume of its interior is given by the integral ${\pi}\int_{0}^{2}f^{2}(z)\, dz$.